# running kinect on ros

Tags: ros, kinect, librviz, freenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi i am currently learning ROS.I am using a xbox 360 kinect sensor ,ROS indigo and ubuntu 14.04.I want to know how to gather the depth information of a kinect sensor through ros ?? what drivers need to be installed ???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220519/running-kinect-on-ros/) by [mruniverse](https://answers.ros.org/users/23403/mruniverse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in the process of trying to figure this out myself, so I won't be able to help you too much but I can point you in the right direction.

You'll need freenect_launch and  libfreenect

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-freenect-launch
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-libfreenect
```

Then you can launch it with (make sure the Kinect is connected, it will tell you to connect it if not)

```
roslanch freenect_launch freenect.launch
```

When it starts it will output some messages like below, which apparently is normal

```
...
[ WARN] [1447125024.427412294]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
[ INFO] [1447125027.019823318]: Stopping device RGB and Depth stream flush.
```

After this you can follow the tutorial from the openni page, starting at step 3
http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/QuickStart

For more information look around on the freenect and openni pages.

-Steven

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2015-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mruniverse](https://answers.ros.org/users/23403/mruniverse/) on 2015-11-19**:
@Steven_Daniluk  thanks a ton it worked :)

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-10-16**:
I have followed it and it is good. However, I am unable to measure depth by this method. In particular, I am using this ([Links](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/QuickStart)). I cannot use this command

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/depth/image
```

Please, suggest